# error: package directory 'ultrafinance' does not exist

Tags: python-2.7, google-crawlers

When I'm trying to install google ultra finance in my windows 8, Im getting this error

```
c:\python27\lib\distutils\dist.py:267: UserWarning: Unknown distribution 
option: 'install_not_requires' 
warnings.warn(msg) 
warning: manifest_maker: standard file 'setup.py' not found 
error: package directory 'ultrafinance' does not exist
```

anyone please help me to fix this.

thankyou in advance.